# run any command from configuration file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I write the shared library for jenkins where I have a method that read configuration file (yaml) and should execute commands based on the input.

example for configuration file

```
commands:
  - name: command 1
    command: "sh 'ls -la'"
  - name: command 2
    command: "readYaml file: 'demo.yaml'"
```

the method code

```
def command_executor(config){
   config.commands.each { command ->
      this.script.echo "running ${command.name} command"

      // This is my problem how to run the command
      command.command.execute().text
   }
}
```

The above example is define in my class and I call it from /var/my_command_executer.groovy file

How I can run any command from the string parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below solution:

Create temporary groovy file the predefined method name that call to the command.

Load the temporary file in method and call the method.

Something like

```
def command_executor(config){
   config.commands.each { command ->
      this.script.echo "running ${command.name} command"

      this.script.writeFile file: "temp.groovy" text: """

      def my_command_executor(){
          ${command.command}
      }
      """

      def temp_command_executor = load "temp.groovy"
      temp_command_executor.my_command_executor()

   }
}
```